# Sample X509Certificate2 RawData to use for unit tests?

Tags: encryption, .net-4.0, x509certificate

I'm working on some RSA encryption/decryption unit tests and all of my functions require some certificates. I'm using dependency injection for these certs so for my unit tests, I'd like to just get some sample dummy (but functional) certificate to test my encryption/decryption library. I'd like to do this by hardcoding the RawData of valid certificate in my unit tests' SetUp method.

Where can I find something like this to put into my unit tests' SetUp method? Or how can I create this and pull this "raw data"? I'm not sure exactly what this "RawData" is. If somebody has something posted online (which would obviously be insecure, which is fine for my unit testing purposes), that would be preferable (from a lazy perspective) but I'm fine generating a cert and pulling this data as well.

Comment: So I've tried creating a self-signed certificate. Via the Certs MMC snap-in, I can export it complete with private key. However, when I load it up via `X509Store.Certificates.Find`, the `HasPrivateKey` property is false and the `PrivateKey` property is null. I'm not sure how to get the `RawData` of a cert WITH the private key in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand it but this is what's going on...

I have a helper method that I call:

```
var cert = X509CertificateHelper.LoadCertificate(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, "thumbprintgoeshere");
```

When I call this, `cert` is successfully populated and even `HasPrivateKey` is true. However, if I then do the following:

```
var cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert.RawData);
```

then the resulting cert2 certificate, which is also what appears to be a valid certificate, has `HasPrivateKey` set to false. It appears that the `RawData` property "strips" out the private key (and yes, it's exportable - I have no problems creating a .pfx w/private key and importing it on another system and reproducing this behavior).

Now that I've discovered all of this, my solution is no longer to hardcode the RawData but instead to actually load up a certificate out of the certificate store - exactly what I was trying to avoid doing. If somebody has a better idea, please lay it on me. But until then, I'm calling this a failure and this is my end result. :-(

Answer (score 3):

## Use .Export() instead of .RawData

When the X509Certificate2 has a private key within you can call:

```
var certBytes = certificateWithPrivateKey.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12);
```

Which returns a byte[] similar to .RawData, but it keeps the private key.
To store this in a unit test, you could just have a const string as Base64 of that data. Which you would get from:

```
var certAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(certBytes);
```

You can restore the key from this byte[] by constructing a X509Certificate2 with it:

```
var certificateCopy = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);
// Or from the string:
var certificateCopy2 = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certAsString));
```

Comment: He does not have a certificate in hand to use for copying

Comment: Ty! Worked to me... I had to use X509Certificate2 constructor with flag **X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable**, and so later export with *X509ContentType.Pkcs12*